# CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID are empty

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cmake, mingw

I am currently playing around with [CMake](http://cmake.com) and want to detect the compiler and the compiler version. My current `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

set (PROJECT "a_tour_of_c++")
set (GNUCXX_MINIMUM_VERSION "4.8")
set (CXX_STANDARD "c++11")

message ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")       # C:/dev/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
message ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")    # EMPTY
message ("${CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX}") # EMPTY

if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS GNUCXX_MINIMUM_VERSION)
    message (FATAL_ERROR "GCC version must be at least ${GNUCXX_MINIMUM_VERSION}!")
  endif()
else()
  message (FATAL_ERROR "Invalid compiler!")
endif()

set (BUILD_DIR build)
set (HEADER_DIR include)
set (SOURCE_DIR src)
set (MAIN_FILE ${SOURCE_DIR}/main.cc)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=${CXX_STANDARD}")
project ($(PROJECT))
include_directories (${HEADER_DIR})
add_executable (${BUILD_DIR}/${PROJECT} ${MAIN_FILE})
```

The file is fine and I can sucessfully clean, build and run my cli application with this file (if I comment out the `else`-branch of the compiler check).

The problem is, that both `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` and `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX` are empty (`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is not).

I am using a Microsoft Windows 8 (6.3.9600) operating system and [MinGW](http://mingw.org), more detailed the following tools.

[image: Versions of tools used]

As you can in the screenshot, I use [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org) to simplify the whole build progress.

So my questions are:

1. What are possible reasons, that the mentioned variables are empty?
2. Does any workaround exist for my problem?

And please let me know, if you see any other problems with my (simple) `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Place it **after** `project` command:

```
> cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

message("before:")
message(">    ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
message(">    ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")
message(">    ${CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX}")
message("-----------------")

project(Foo)

message("after:")
message(">    ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
message(">    ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")
message(">    ${CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX}")
message("-----------------")

> cmake -H. -B_builds
before:
>    
>    
>    
-----------------
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
after:
>    /usr/bin/c++
>    GNU
>    1
-----------------
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /.../_builds
```

Answer (score 5):

It *might* help you tell CMake that this is a C++ project. To do it you say it in the `project` command:

```
project ($(PROJECT) CXX)
#                   ^^^
# Note project type
```

You might also want to do it before checking the variable.

Comment: Moving the `project` command was sufficient. I've modified the start of my `CMakeLists.txt` as follows: `cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

set (PROJECT_NAME "a_tour_of_c++")
set (PROJECT_TYPE "CXX")

project (${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_TYPE})`

Comment: Be careful of `project ($(PROJECT) CXX)`. I tried to enable it on our C++ project and a bunch of CMake built-in tests failed because it expected a C compiler. I asked about it on Stack Overflow but got no answers.

Comment: @jww I hope you figured it out by now, but many C-specific tests also have C++ specific variants. For example [`CheckIncludeFile`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFile.html) is the C variant, [`CheckIncludeFileCXX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFileCXX.html#module:CheckIncludeFileCXX) is the C++ variant.