# Variable is empty after executing command on MinGW and MinGW-64?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw32, mingw-w64

We are struggling with a failed CMake build on MinGW and MinGW-64. Our project is a C++ library. Our [`CMakeLists.txt`](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L104) has a block like below. The block identifies the target platform through the compiler (other methods are too unreliable, especially on ARM, MIPS and PPC):

```
set(SHELL_CMD sh -c)
set(GREP_CMD egrep -i -c)

execute_process(COMMAND ${SHELL_CMD} "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpmachine 2>&1"
    COMMAND ${GREP_CMD} "amd64"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRYPTOPP_AMD64
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

...

# http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/466
execute_process(COMMAND ${SHELL_CMD} "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpmachine 2>&1"
    COMMAND ${GREP_CMD} "mingw32"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRYPTOPP_MINGW32
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

# http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/466
execute_process(COMMAND ${SHELL_CMD} "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpmachine 2>&1"
    COMMAND ${GREP_CMD} "w64-mingw32"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRYPTOPP_MINGW64
OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

It succeeds on 9 of 11 platforms, but fails for MinGW and MinGW-64. From our [bug report](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/466) tracking the issue, the following on MinGW-64:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${SHELL_CMD} "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpmachine 2>&1"
    COMMAND ${GREP_CMD} "w64-mingw32"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRYPTOPP_MINGW64
OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

message(STATUS ${CRYPTOPP_MINGW64})

execute_process(COMMAND ${SHELL_CMD} "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpmachine 2>&1"
    COMMAND ${GREP_CMD} "mingw32"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRYPTOPP_MINGW32
OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

message(STATUS ${CRYPTOPP_MINGW32})
```

The statements produce an empty message. Removing `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` does not affect the issue. And running `c++ -dumpmachine | egrep -i -c w64-mingw32` from the MinGW terminal produces expected results.

We found [CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20904914/608639) but it does not seem to apply since the compiler is set in our case. (It is the only other "cmake empty variable mingw" we have found).

Unfortunately, I don't know what version of Cmake is being used. Our [bug report](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/466) includes the CMake output, but CMake fails to print its version numbers.

Why is CMake failing to set the variables `CRYPTOPP_MINGW64` and `CRYPTOPP_MINGW32` on MinGW and MinGW-64?

---

Here's a typical output from CMake while configuring.

```
=== Building cryptopp ===
mkdir -p deps/cryptopp/build/
cd deps/cryptopp/build/ && cmake -G 'MSYS Makefiles' -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_TESTING=OFF -D BUILD_SHARED=OFF -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=native" ../ && make
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Compiler: 
-- Flags: -march=native
-- Build type: Release
-- 
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * Threads

-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:503 (add_dependencies):
  Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in
  add_dependencies.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0046" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The dependency target "clean" of target "distclean" does not exist.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/msys32/home/buildbot/slave/kovri-all-win32/build/deps/cryptopp/build
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate your arguments from the commands.

```
set(SHELL_CMD sh)
set(SHELL_CMD_ARGS "-c")
set(GREP_CMD egrep)
set(GREP_CMD_ARGS "-i -c")

execute_process(COMMAND ${SHELL_CMD} "${SHELL_CMD_ARGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpmachine 2>&1"
```

Comment: Thanks @vre. Let me give it a go. Unfortunately, I don't have a MinGW machine for testing, so I have to ask someone else to perform the test. But I can test the change on the other platforms.

Comment: Another question (if you don't mind): should the arguments be quoted separately? I.e., `execute_process(COMMAND "${SHELL_CMD}" "${SHELL_CMD_ARGS}" "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" "-dumpmachine" "2>&1"`? The CMake documents for [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) don't explain things very well, and don't offer examples  (*q.v.*).

Comment: It appears the documentation problem has existed for years. Here's an example of the problem dating from 2011: [cmake execute_process() always fails with “No such file or directory” when I call git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6797395/608639). It befuddles me when a project won't fix its documentation. What's the point in allowing users to make the same mistakes over and over again, year after year?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference. Only the argument after COMMAND needs to name the exact command.

Comment: We reported the documentation problems on the CMake mailing list: [Please update the documentation for execute_process](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2017-August/066140.html). Hopefully we will have an answer soon regarding both quoting and commas.

Comment: Thanks again @VRE. So it looks like the changes did not [fix the problem](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/466#issuecomment-325036687). Very frustrating...

Comment: I also thought that would work out. To gain further insight what is malfunctioning I would try to print the output of the execute_process command. e.g. `execute_process(COMMAND ${SHELL_CMD} "${SHELL_CMD_ARGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpmachine 2>&1" OUTPUT_VARIABLE out_msg ERROR_VARIABLE err_msg ) message(STATUS "${out_msg} ${err_msg}")` I would also add CXX as last argument to the project command.

Comment: Thanks. We tried to add `CXX` to the project but it broke earlier versions of CMake. We had problems on Fedora 15, CentOS 5, OpenBSD 4 and Ubuntu 10. (We support back further than that. We had to compromise some for CMake users). Also see [Tell CMake to use C++ compiler for C files coming from CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37931068/608639)

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be use of `SHELL_CMD`, `sh -c` and positional arguments. First, `SHELL_CMD` needed to be `sh` only. Second, the `-c` argument needed to follow the command separately. Third, we needed to quote the entire string. Related, see [Why doesn't echo called as /bin/sh -c echo foo output anything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253422/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

We don't know where the use of `sh` like that came from. We're guessing it was cobbled together way back when and the cruft remained until it caused a problem. It probably should have failed on all platforms. We still don't know if `2>&1` is correct. Its unfortunate CMake docs for [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/execute_process.html) are not well explained and offer no examples.

We changed our target machine detection code to the following. The code now quotes the argument to `sh` to avoid problems with argument passing.

```
function(DumpMachine output pattern)
  execute_process(
      COMMAND sh -c "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpmachine 2>&1"
      COMMAND egrep -i -c "${pattern}"
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${output}
      OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  set(${output} "${${output}}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction(DumpMachine)

DumpMachine(CRYPTOPP_AMD64 "amd64|x86_64")
DumpMachine(CRYPTOPP_I386 "i.86")
DumpMachine(CRYPTOPP_MINGW32 "\\<mingw32\\>")
DumpMachine(CRYPTOPP_MINGW64 "w64-mingw32|mingw64")
DumpMachine(CRYPTOPP_X32 "x32")
DumpMachine(CRYPTOPP_AARCH32 "Aarch32")
DumpMachine(CRYPTOPP_AARCH64 "Aarch64")
DumpMachine(CRYPTOPP_ARM "\\<arm\\>|armhf|arm7l")
```